# Creating a column to correctly group by effort

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to create a column to correctly label changes in effort by Estimator.

I've been able to get close using the below code with DENSE_RANK() function, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm having trouble identifying the start and end points to organize by. I've include the current and desired output below.

Current Code:

```
SELECT *,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Estimator, Effort) AS Group
FROM #Estimating_with_Breakpoints
ORDER BY Estimator, Date, DateType
```

Current output:

```
Job Name                    DateType    Date        Effort  Group
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Start       3/8/2017    50      6
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Breakpoint  4/13/2017   50      6
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Finish      4/13/2017   0       4
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Breakpoint  5/1/2017    0       4
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Start       5/1/2017    33      5
Bonita Springs Library      Breakpoint  5/22/2017   33      5
North Ft. Myers Library     Breakpoint  5/22/2017   83      7
Bonita Springs Library      Start       5/22/2017   83      7
North Ft. Myers Library     Start       5/22/2017   133     9
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Breakpoint  6/5/2017    133     9
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Finish      6/5/2017    100     8
Bonita Springs Library      Breakpoint  6/19/2017   100     8
North Ft. Myers Library     Breakpoint  6/19/2017   50      6
Bonita Springs Library      Finish      6/19/2017   50      6
North Ft. Myers Library     Finish      6/19/2017   0       4
```

Desired output:

```
Job Name                    DateType    Date        Effort  Group
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Start       3/8/2017    50      1
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Breakpoint  4/13/2017   50      1
Hidden Lakes Apartments     Finish      4/13/2017   0       2
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Breakpoint  5/1/2017    0       2
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Start       5/1/2017    33      3
Bonita Springs Library      Breakpoint  5/22/2017   33      3
North Ft. Myers Library     Breakpoint  5/22/2017   83      3
Bonita Springs Library      Start       5/22/2017   83      3
North Ft. Myers Library     Start       5/22/2017   133     4
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Breakpoint  6/5/2017    133     4
Dr. Biggs Joint Institute   Finish      6/5/2017    100     5
Bonita Springs Library      Breakpoint  6/19/2017   100     5
North Ft. Myers Library     Breakpoint  6/19/2017   50      5
Bonita Springs Library      Finish      6/19/2017   50      5
North Ft. Myers Library     Finish      6/19/2017   0       5
```

Comment: can you explain more about what you're trying to do? for example, what do the last 5 rows of your desired output have in common that would put them in a group together?

Comment: Great question. Essentially we're forcing a line graph to a have a "start" and "stop" point to draw lateral lines. The commonality is the date, 6/19, so the line drawn would extend from 6/5 to 6/19 @ 0 effort (given it is the final #)

Comment: Can you provide some sample raw data?